# Push data using routes in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to have an api which stores the information into my CRM, to push the details I've following parameters/details to store into the data:

`Called_number, caller_number, agent_number, date, time, call_status, total_call_duration, Call_UUID, Recording_URL, conversation_duration`

I've created the migration table with the same data name mentioned above, request protocol is HTTP, request data type is Query String and response data type is JSON.

Data is being sent by simple URL from third party so I'm using simple post route to insert the data into the database like this:

```
Route::post('/calllogs/{called_number}/{caller_number}/{agent_number}/{date}/{time}/{call_status}/{total_call_duration}/{call_UUID}/{recording_URL}/{converstation_duration}', 'CalllogController@insert')
```

Is there any way to secure this with some dynamic API keys to prevent inserting fake data? I mean any person having idea of the URL, can make the url and will insert data into my database, I want to have something like this:

```
Route::post('/calllogs/{api_key}/{caller_number}....
```

where I can check the `api_key` dynamically and then insert into the database.

Thanks.

Comment: @Loek 's answer is good. If you need a bigger system for API authentification, you can also look at Laravel Passport: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This library (API Guard)](https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard) is probably what you're looking for, it does exactly what you want: securing API calls with authorization keys.

Comment: Thanks, this will help.. :)